# How do I use SCP with two different ports on each IP in script bash

Tags: ssh, scp

How do I use `scp` with two different ports on each IP.

```
SSH LOCAL : IP=111.111.111.111 & port=22
```

I have a redirection ports on a router

EXAMPLE SCRIPT BASH:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"

array[1]=192.168.20.159
array[2]="192.168.20.159 -p 24"

scp /home/innobing/video/$video pi@$i:/home/pi/video/$video.new
```

RESULT IN ARRAY [2]:

```
ssh: connect to host 24 port 22: Invalid argument
lost connection
```

There is a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to mention a source port, it will be a auto-generated (>=1024).

Also to mention a custom port number use `-P` option, `-p` is to preserve metadata.

Do:

```
scp -P 24 /home/aa/video/a.mp4 user@222.222.222.222:/home/aa/video/a.mp4.new
```

Answer (score 3):

`scp -P 24 /home/aa/video/a.mp4 user@222.222.222.222:/home/aa/video/a.mp4.new`

The "P" is upper case. You don't need to worry about the "local port", scp can access the filesystem directly, it doesn't need the network for it.